# Listen Property Changed Events in a weak mode for Windows Phone 8.1 RT

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have the following object:

```
public class EventCounter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _count = 0;
    public int Count {
        get
        {
            return _count;
        }
        set
        {
            _count = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Count");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to get notified everytime the Count value is changed with with a "weak event pattern"

How can I do it?

Comment: MSDN has a [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on this topic. What do you need beyond that?

Comment: I'm starting with windows phone and I don't know how to exactly implement it. I'm looking for a concrete example. Some classes in the page you linked are not available in Windows RT 8.1:(

Comment: I'm not sure but PropertyChangedEventManager and should be available in Windows RT. It has methods AddHandler (for delegates) and AddListener (for IWeakEventListener). Call one of them with an EventCounter as source, your listener and `"Count"` as propertyName.

Comment: PropertyChangedEventManager is not available in Windows Store\RT.